# Почему не подставляется текст в поле autocomplete?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Есть код:

```
input id="searchTerm" name="searchTerm" type="text" /


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#searchTerm").autocomplete({
        source: "/Company/GetSearchValue",
        select: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.item) {
                $("#searchTerm").val(ui.item.value);

            }
        }
    });
});
```

Вот в видно что вернул сервер и выбираю вариант.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но вместо текста подставляется id. Почему?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я всё думал, в какое поле не текст, а число подставляется... Вы сами заменяете текст на `id` вот этой строчкой кода `$("#searchTerm").val(ui.item.value);`. Удалите её, и у вас будет текст.

Comment: Убрал. Не помогает. Правда скрипт немного изменил. Пытался и так, но та же проблема `<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[data-autocomplete-source]").each(function () {
            var target = $(this);
            target.autocomplete({
                source: target.attr("data-autocomplete-source"),
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                    $('input[data-company-id]').val(ui.item.value);
                    $("#searchTerm").val(ui.item.label);
                    
                }
            });
        })
    });
</script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо возвращать массив строк:

```
["ромашка", "раста", "маста"]
```

А ты возвращаешь массив объектов.

Тебе надо либо с контроллера возвращать корректные данные (массив), либо полученные данные преобразовывать в массив.

```
target.autocomplete({
  source: target.attr("data-autocomplete-source") 

  response: function(event, ui) {
    ui.content.forEach(function (item) {
      item.value = item.Id;
      item.label = item.Name;
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: По разному пробовал. Везде в примерах как у меня. Но у меня упорно id ставится
     `
`public ActionResult GetSearchValue(string term){
            var models = db.Companies.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(term))
                             .Select(a => new
                             {
                                 value = a.Id,
                                 label = a.Name
                             }).Distinct();
           return Json(models, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }`